# ASP.NET UserControl Does Not Initialize Child Controls

Tags: .net, asp.net

Inside my page, I have the following:

```
<aspe:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanel">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <local:KeywordSelector runat="server" ID="ksKeywords" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</aspe:UpdatePanel>
```

The `KeywordSelector` control is a control I define in the same assembly and `local` is mapped to its namespace.

The control is made up of several other controls and is defined as such:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
            CodeBehind="KeywordSelector.ascx.cs"
            Inherits="Keywords.KeywordSelector" %>
```

and has quite a few server controls of its own, all defined as members in the `.designer.cs` file.

However, **during no part of the control's lifecycle does it have any child control objects nor does it produce HTML**:

1. All of the members defined in the `.designer.cs` file are `null`.
2. Calls to `HasControls` return `false`.
3. Calls to `EnsureChildControls` do nothing.
4. The `Controls` collection is empty.

Removing the `UpdatePanel` did no good. I tried to reproduce it in a clean page with a new `UserControl` and the same thing happens.

I am using ASP.NET over .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 with the integrated web server.

What am I missing here?

**Update #1:** Following Rob's comment, I looked into `OnInit` and found that the `UserControl` does not detect that it has any child controls. Moreover, `CreateControlCollection` is never called!

Comment: Did you override OnInit and delete the line base.OnInit(e); on accident?

Comment: No. I also just checked and it gets called before my Page_Load method, so that's OK, I guess.

Comment: Bummer - was hoping it'd be an easy one :)

Comment: Are you dynamically loading this control?

Comment: Nope. Read about those too...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, I've found the problem(s):

1. *User Controls*, as opposed to *Custom Controls* must be registered one-by-one in the *web.config* file. Do this:

   `<add tagPrefix="local" tagName="KeywordSelector" src="~/KeywordSelector.ascx"  />`

   instead of:

   `<add tagPrefix="local" namespace="Keywords" assembly="Keywords" />`
2. You should never place a `WebControl` in the same directory as the `Control` that is using it. This is downright silly. [Read about it here](http://www.mertner.com/morten/?p=31).

Thanks for the help. Now if only I could mark my own answer as **the** answer...

Comment: Glad it helped someone else :)

Comment: Just spent hours trying to solve this! Very obscure problem (and too many false positive hits when trying to Bing an answer for it). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this helped me discover something weird for myself.  You can also <@Register it in the page.  In my scenario, I have some of my own Validator controls and I need to register them via assembly to use them.  Me using the User Control compiled and ran because the namespace was available, but the markup (and expected auto creation of child controls) was not being processed.  My solution was to register both the namespace and the user control.  So I basically ended up with both of your lines above (except I used @Register on the host page itself).  Cheers!

Comment: Beside changing the `web.config` I had to add `<% Register %>` to the page in the form of: `<%@ Register TagPrefix="custom" Namespace="CustomControls" Assembly="CurrentAssembly" %>`

Answer (score 1):

In my case the reason was the Resharper 7.1 added incorrect @Register directive at the top of aspx - instead of this desired row:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/Hello/Hello.ascx" TagName="Hello" TagPrefix="p" %>
```

i got wrong one:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="p" Namespace="MyNamespace.WebApp.Controls" Assembly="MyApp.Web" %>
```