# ASP.NET: How to initialize when *user control* is initially loaded

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have an ASP.NET user control that I'm embedding in another user control. This works fine.

I need to know the best logic/method for detecting when the *control* is loaded. In other words, I have some display initialization logic that needs to run when the control is initially displayed. Surely there is a pattern for this.

The typical method is to put (!IsPostBack) logic in the Page_Load method of the control. This works great until you end up with a state when the Parent page has already posted back many times. My user control gets added to the page but its display does not intialize properly.

I'm hoping to find a way that keeps this logic inside the control, versus various hacking around in the codebehind of the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

See the [following MS article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx).  They have an example that places several controls within a user control and initializes them.

Answer (score -1):

There is another post here on StackOverflow that seems similar.  You may want to [check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243232/asp-net-usercontrol-does-not-initialize-child-controls), and see if it points you in the right direction.

It may also be helpful to [review the page life-cycle and events](http://john-sheehan.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/aspnet-life-cycles-events.pdf).

Comment: This answer should've rather been a comment.