# Adding Control to Container Control that is in User Control - How to properly initialize?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

Let's say I have a user control MyUserControl, which has a **container** control (it's a server control, but it could just be a Panel) and a dropdownlist.  The dropdownlist is not in the container control initially.  In it's code-behind, I am overriding OnInit and creating the user control, which includes populating a dropdownlist and adding that dropdownlist to my container control.  I have a public property Year, which is an int.  Based on the value of Year, I want to populate the dropdownlist.  The problem is that in OnInit, year is always 0.

On the page Init, I am setting year, but that doesn't run until AFTER the control's Init runs.  If I try to set the value on PreInit on the page, the page hasn't initialized the control and I get invalid null reference when setting a value to the control.

My question is:  How can I properly initialize the control?  How can I set the value on the page, before the control actually gets initialized?

If I move the control's code to OnLoad, it'll work until I have to do a postback.  In this case I need to, though!

Answer (score 0):

Set the properties in **PreRender** of your user control.

And I am assuming you are **registering** the User Control ***properly***:

[Check the accepted answer here >>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243232/asp-net-usercontrol-does-not-initialize-child-controls)

Comment: I'm actually adding controls to another control on the user control.  I have a reason for this, but let's say I have a Placeholder control and I'm adding the controls (including this dropdownlist) to it in OnInit.  If I added them in prerender the structure wouldn't be properly created when the ViewState is set for the control.  So...the dropdownlist would have a selectedindex of 0 after it gets bound on postback, even though the user selected index 7.

Comment: @LionelHutz It would be great if you gave the exact scenario.And edited your question to reflect that.

Comment: Took your suggestion.  Thanks for the help.